# Prove a generator of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

### Definitions

Let $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) := \left \{M := \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}: \det{M} = 1 \right \}$ with matrix multiplication be a group of $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Let

\begin{align}
  A_\lambda :&= \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0\\ 0 & \lambda^{-1}\end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \text{ with }\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}\\
  B_t :&= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & t\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \text{ with } t \in \mathbb{R}\\
  C :&= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})
\end{align}

be elements of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

### Question

Do $A_\lambda, B_t$ and $C$ generate $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$?

### My try

I think they do. When I could show that

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$$

can be multiplied with a combination of the three matrices $A, B, C$ in such a way that the result is the neutral element of this group
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
then I could generate the matrix by multiplying the inverse matrices. 
The inverse matrices can be generated because:

\begin{align}
  A_\lambda^{-1} &= A_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}\\
  B_t^{-1}       &= B_{-t}\\
  C^{-1}         &= C^3
\end{align}

Now the only thing left is to get from 
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$$
to
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Ok. So let's try it.

#### Case 1: $a = 0$

As $\det(M)=1 = ad - bc = 0d-bc$ we know that $bc=-1$. Especially is $c \neq 0$.

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} c & d\\ -a & -b\end{pmatrix}$$

Continue with Case 2.

#### Case 2: $a \neq 0$

Normalize ($M \cdot A_{\frac{1}{a}}$):

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{a} & 0\\ 0 & a\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & ab\\ \frac{c}{a} & ad\end{pmatrix}$$

Continue with Case 3.

#### Case 3: $a=1$

Get a $0$ with $M \cdot B_{-b}$:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -b\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ c & d-bc\end{pmatrix}$$

We know that $\det{M} = 1 = ad - bc = d - bc$.

Continue with Case 4.

#### Case 4: $a=1$, $b=0, d=1$

At this stage we have matrices that look like

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ c & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

This is where I'm stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: Is n't $( d - bc ) = 1 $ from case 3 ?

Comment: @DiffeoR: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: Is not the case 4 det 1 ?

Comment: Yes, but in how far does that help? Every matrix $M$ here has $\det M = 1$. I have to get to the neutral element of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Case 4** you have $d=1$ since the determinant is still $1$, then
$$
A_{-1} C B_c C \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ c & 1} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}.
$$